# Is there any way to disable automatic type coercion in SQL Server 2005/2008, from varchar to int (as an example)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion, type-coercion

If I have the following SQL:

```
INSERT INTO sometable (someintcolumn) VALUES ('1')
```

This will succeed, inserting the value 1.

Is there any way I can ask SQL Server to please don't convert the types for me, permanently or temporarily, and instead fail the above SQL execution?

We have a large import project that we'd like to fix all SQL's for, but that requires meticulously going through all SQL's and analyzing the data types of all columns. Since this is executed against test databases on our servers, we'd like to get our server to tell us when we've got the data types wrong.

Comment: No. Vote for it here https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/260762/add-optional-checks-for-more-robust-development

Comment: It'd be useful to see if we had an "implicit conversion" trap in Profiler

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Martin says SQL Server can't do it. I wonder how hard it would be to cut the type conversion code out of an open source dbms.